# Using protobuf-net with WCF and Silverlight

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-5.0, protobuf-net

We've tried all sorts of things but Protobuf seems to be the most lightweight and fastest.
Now our problem is that we're using Silverlight as a client which does not make it easy to swap out the defaultserializers for WCF.

Is there any improvement in this area with protobuf-net?

Or are there any other suggestions in how we could speed up our webservice?

I like the WDSL which WCF generates on the client side so I'd like to stick with that. However manually doing requests is fine aswell, eventhough it would take a considerable amount of time to swap out our old service.

Comment: The "send a Stream or byte[]" is the only thing I can suggest, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We basically ended up passing data as `Byte[]` arrays and manually handling the serialization/deserialization.  There is a bit of additional work to do it this way, but in the end, it gave us better flexibility (especially with a few problem objects that Protobuf didn't really want to serialize).

Comment: Which serialization does WCF use then? Did you change the binding to something else? At the moment we're using basicHttpBinding with the default XMLserializer.

Comment: We use a `basicHttpBinding` using binary serialization, and then just use a return type of byte[] for the service methods.  That allows us to serialize the return objects before returning them, and deserialize them once they are on the client in byte array form.  We use a shared library that contains the types you are working with so that both sides can serialize and deserialize as necessary.

Comment: Nice, we'll try that and see if it goes faster! Thanks for the explanation!